# Route to the url when user clicks on notifications in pwa, angular 6 and web-push in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, angular6, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I am working on pushing the notifications in PWA using SwPush in Angular6. For this I am using @angular/service-worker. I am able to send the notifications from node server. But when I click on the received notification, it is not able to route the desired url. I am using `web-push module in node.js`, and this is the payload:

```
        "payload": {
        "title": "Sample Notification",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action": "opentweet",
            "url":"https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com",
            "title": "Open tweet"
          }
        ],
        "body": "A sample data to check the notification availability!",
        "dir": "auto",
        "icon": "https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "badge": "https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "lang": "en",
        "url": "https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com",
        "renotify": true,
        "requireInteraction": true,
        "tag": 926796012340920300,
        "vibrate": [
          100,
          50,
          100
        ],
        "data": {
          "url": "https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com",
          "favorite_count": 0,
          "retweet_count": 0
        }
      }
```

I am using

```
var webPush=require('web-push');

//sub is userSubscriptionObject to send the notifications to subscribed user browser.
webPush.sendNotification(sub, JSON.stringify(payload))))
```

In angular,

```js
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any = [];
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private router: Router, 
    private swPush: SwPush) {
    console.log('this is index');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCoins();
  }
  subscribeNotifications(){
        this.swPush.requestSubscription({
      serverPublicKey: "BMW3STH0ODuNdhFVAZIy8FUDEwt2f8LLpWBiBnz8WE0_558rZc4aLbZUD9y-HxMlfCtyE5OD0mk3xa2oFJZu5n0"
    }).then(sub => {
        console.log("Notification Subscription: ", sub);
        this
        .http
        .post('https://e1a2e469.ngrok.io/sub/subscribeNotifications', sub);.subscribe(
          () => {
            console.log('Sent push subscription object to server.');        
        },
          err => console.log('Could not send subscription object to server, reason: ', err)
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.error("Could not subscribe to notifications", err));
  }
  unsubscribeNotifications(){
    this.swPush.subscription.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(subscriptionValue=>{
      console.log('this is un subscription', subscriptionValue);
        this
        .http
        .post('https://e1a2e469.ngrok.io/sub/unsubscribeNotifications', subscriptionValue);
          .subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log('[App] Delete subscriber request answer', res)
            // Unsubscribe current client (browser)
            subscriptionValue.unsubscribe()
              .then(success => {
                console.log('[App] Unsubscription successful', success)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log('[App] Unsubscription failed', err)
              })
          },
          err => {
            console.log('[App] Delete subscription request failed', err)
          }
    );
  });
}
  sendNotifications(){
    console.log('subscribeNotifications')
    this
      .http
      .post('https://e1a2e469.ngrok.io/sub/sendNotifications', null).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('subscribed successfully');
    });
  }
}
```

My intention is, when user clicks on the notification it is supposed to route to

`https://pwa-sw-push-notifications.firebaseapp.com`.

I have tried giving this URL in different parameters in the above object like `actions[0].action.url` `URL` `data.url` and nothing worked. So I am confused where to give the URL to make it possible. Could anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your payload, as far as I can see. The payload is just a data which is delivered to your browser, on your browser side you need to implement `notificationClick` handler in order to process the payload data i.e., navigating to the desired URL. A simple `notifictionClick` handler can be implemented in service worker as follow:

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received. event', event);
    event.notification.close();
    if (clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
      event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
    }
  });
```

For reference check out the links below:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20956#issuecomment-374133852
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1

Comment: I am just confusing where to add this event listener. I have just updated the question, can you revise once?

Comment: @ramprakashseepana I have added links, please check them out

Comment: @tajeshwi, I have updated the question. Can you check it once?

Comment: as I am using angular6, it is automatically creating the ngsw-worker.js. So I am confusing where to add the addEventListener method. So I have gone with different approach for subscription and pushing notifications.

Comment: Got it, solved my issue. Thank you @Tejeshwi for spending your time.

Comment: Can someone provide a solution for providing notification click ?

Comment: @Bhuneshwer I think someone will surely, if you create a proper question and show what you've done and what issues you are facing.

Comment: ngsw-worker.js is generated, so editing it is not appropriate. See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449020/angular6-service-worker-and-background-sync

Comment: Here is also a tutorial to do this, though without angular (look for 'Handle a Push Event')https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/