# Angular6 Service Worker and background sync

Tags: angular6, angular-service-worker

it seems that *angular6* does not support background syncing with service worker. What are the steps required to do this without any library in an angular service?

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync

How and where can I access *WorkerGlobalScope* in an *angular6* application directly so that background sync can be done.:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
    event.waitUntil(doSomeStuff());
  }
});
```

The problem is that the angular CLI generates the servicworker file (*ngsw-worker.js*). Is there a way to *inject* / *modify*  / *extend* this file? Yes, i can edit the file *ngsw-worker.js* by hand or with another fancy trick. Is there an official way to do this?

Comment: I also had the idea to add two serviceworkers, but this seems not to work https://gist.github.com/bahmutov/36b4b6e8f17b1edd69484a271b7c8634

Comment: Salü. Looks like they haven't implemented it yet in ngsw-worker.js :-( As an alternative you can use workbox as a Service Worker Library. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync

Comment: @yonexbat **Please try this its working with using some customization code**  https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/12/background-sync-ng.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can use your custom script to extend the capabilities of Angular's service worker.

Just follow below steps:

1. Create a js file with your custom script let's say `sw-custom.js`
   under src directory of your project.
2. Add "`importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js')`" at top of `sw-custom.js` file.
3. Add `sw-custom.js` file to `angular.json` file under scripts section.
4. Now register your `sw-custom.js` file in app module instead of

ngsw-worker.js

That's it now you can write your script here as per your need.

Maybe it is not correct approach but it works.

Here is the [blog](http://jakubcodes.pl/2018/06/13/enhancing-angular-ngsw/) for same.

Comment: Tnx. This seems to work. I had to register the script sw-custom.js in angular.json, so it will be copied to the dist folder.

Comment: Blog on Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190103022602/http://jakubcodes.pl/2018/06/13/enhancing-angular-ngsw/